# Mongo Get-Mdbcdata Filter count vs. db.getCollection

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodb-query

I am comparing the count of a filtered query in a Mongo collection between Get-Mdbcdata and db.getCollection. Using Get-Mdbcdata -Filter and -Count parameters, the result count is half of what db.getCollection count function that is filtered with the same condition as -Filter in Get-Mdbcdata. This is the code for Get-Mdbcdata.

```
function Get-CollectionFiltered {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $Database,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $CollectionName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $FieldAttribute,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [hashtable] $Filter
    )
    try {
    
        $output =  $FieldAttribute
        Connect-Mdbc $Url $Database $CollectionName -CollectionVariable MyColl;
        #Write-Output $output
        $cnt = Get-MdbcData -Collection $MyColl -Filter $Filter -Count
        Write-Output "count = $cnt"
        
        $data = Get-MdbcData -Collection $MyColl -Filter $Filter -Sort "{_id:1}" -Project "{$output}"  | Export-MdbcData $Path -Append;
    } catch { 
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message
    } finally {
      
    }
}
$dte = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-8)
$query = @{ updated_date = @{ '$gte' = $dte }}
Get-CollectionFiltered -Url $Url -Database $Database -CollectionName $CollectionName   -FieldAttribute $FieldAttribute -Path $tempfile -Filter $query
```

This is the command used in Robo 3T for db.getCollection.

```
db.getCollection('mycoll').count({"updated_date": { $gte : new Date("2022-08-24") }})
```

Is there something incorrect or missing in any of the filters I am using for either methods?